# What's the definition of a prime Gaussian integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The units are considered to be primes, namely, $1,-1,i,-i$. Why?

Comment: It is a Euclidean domain, and the norm is the usual norm on complex numbers. So a unit must have norm 1, and these are the only 4 Gaussian integers satisfying this. Primes have nothing to do with this.

Comment: The units are not considered to be primes.

Comment: prime gaussian integers?

Comment: it is a principal ideal domain, so the primes are as in $\mathbb{Z}$ : the non-units integers $p$ s.t. there is no non-unit $m$ dividing $p$, so that the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain)

Comment: In integral domains primes and units are two very different things: units are invertible elements, primes are primes. In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we have four units, $\pm 1,\pm i$, while primes are the elements $a+bi$ such that $a^2+b^2\in\mathbb{N}$ is an integer prime or the square of an integer prime of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: Ok, I am having troubles with the following claim. The 4 gaussian integers of norm=2 are 1+i,1-i,-1-i and -1+i are associates of the prime 1+i, so for example 1+i=(1-i)i=1+i, so 1-i is prime and i is prime right?

Comment: Basically the associates of a prime number are primes. Is that correct?

Comment: @daniel: a prime multiplied by a unity is still a prime, but that does not mean that every unity is a prime. Also because otherwise UFD would mean nothing. In $\mathbb{Z}$, $-3$ and $3$ are associated primes, $-1$ and $1$ are units.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the Gaussian integers.  A nonzero, nonunit $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is called prime if whenever $\pi =\alpha\beta$, we must have either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ as a unit.  And no, units are not prime, as they are specifically excluded from the definition.  $1+i$ is prime, and so is its associate $1-i$.  But $i$ is not prime.  It's kinda like how $-p$ and $p$ are both prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, but $-1$ is not prime; it's a unit.

Comment: So we exclude the units from the prime factorization like we do it with the integers.

Comment: @daniel Not really.  Each nonzero, nonunit $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $\alpha=u\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_k$, for some unit $u$ and primes $\pi_i$. But then it's no longer unique, as you can exchange $u$ for any unit, and just switch out $\pi_1$ for an associate of $\pi_1$

Comment: @daniel I meant $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, not $\mathbb{Z}$, though it is still true.

Comment: ummmmm so Gaussian integers don't have unique prime factorization?

Comment: @daniel: *unique* factorization always means *unique diregarding invertible elements*. Also in $\mathbb{Z}$, $-3$ is a prime, but $-3=(-1)\cdot 3$. That does not violate the UFD property of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @daniel They have a different kind of uniqueness.  Typically it's called "unique up to associates and the order in which they are multiplied", but that's a mouthful, so it's just called uniqueness.  This is the same in $\mathbb{Z}$ though.  Take $6 \in \mathbb{Z}$ for example.  $6=2\cdot 3=(-1)(-2)(3)=(-1)(2)(-3)=(-2)(-3)$.

Comment: since Gaussian integers are a UFD, it isn't really a problem, but that definition you give is really of irreducible, not prime.  $p$ is prime if $p \mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Comment: I am just imagining danger ahead if they start looking at $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ next where $6=(1+ \sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ is a factorization into irreducibles that are not prime.  Obviously you can also factor it $6=2\cdot 3$ so you see it does not have a unique irreducible factorization

Comment: @CPM Of course, but the OP didn't make a distinguishment, so I assumed they will eventually be taught the difference.  In the meantime, I wanted to give an explanation that helped

Comment: Technically you provided a definition for *irreducible* elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, not primes.

Comment: @Oiler Yes I know